# Hello,I want to know the exact scenerio where in we can declare same method as get and post?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I want to know the exact scenerio where in we can declare same method as get and post?
i have used the case but still not able to find right explaination

```
@RequestMapping(value =url, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView fetchLrmPart1(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return this.getPart1Page(request, model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = url, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView fetchLRMGet(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return this.getPart1Page(request, model);
}
```

Comment: Add appropriate tag and description as well

Comment: You can do that, but you shouldn't. A GET and a POST don't have the same semantic. Basically, you use GET to obtain an existing resource, and you use POST to create a non-existing resource.

Comment: Eclipse is just your development environment. This question is nothing to do with Eclipse - please edit your question and add some better tags - which programming language? What framework?